# Minimum data required to send a valid SqlParameter

Tags: c#, sql, sqlparameter

I have noticed a strange behavior while building parameters for a stored procedure I call. Within a table used there's a column that has the type VARCHAR(16). When I build the parameter for this column my first instinct was to do it like this:

```
ret = new SqlParameter();
ret.ParameterName = name;
ret.Value = (string)value;
```

This approach gave me an error saying `String or binary data would be truncated`.

The method that works is when I build the parameter as such:

```
ret = new SqlParameter(name, type, length);
ret.ParameterName = name;
ret.Value = (string)value;
```

The interesting thing is that when I set a length for a varchar parameter, if the value is an empty string, the stored procedure will go on without a hitch. When I however put a singe letter or more in the value field, the same error appears.

My questions are why it accepts a parameter that is null or empty with an incorrect declaration of length, and what is the minimal info you have to give a parameter in c# so that it will be passed correctly?

Comment: Please post more concrete code. Create an executable repro. Show us how you try to insert into a temp table with the same schema.

Comment: I use one line adding parameter like `com.Parameters.Add("@abc", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = 100;`. Where `com` is an `SqlCommand` object.

Comment: @usr I'm asking if someone knows of the top of their head, you don't need to debug my programs to find me an answer, I'll do that.

Comment: From memory, `Varchar` will default to `30` or `50`, so I assume the warning is telling you that if you don't specify a length, anything over the default will be `truncated`.

Comment: @christiandev When you put the length to over 9000, if your string length is below 1 (empty) then the stored procedure will be called and it will run with no problems, but as soon as the value has `.length > 0` the error shows it self. I was wondering why in some cases the length property is ignored and in others it isn't.